# PHPUnit Database Testing: How To Use Dataset Per Test?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, dbunit

I want to seed a database table(s) with data, perform some operations using the library I'm building, and finally test those table(s) against another dataset of expected values. I'm using yaml files.

So far I can get this working with this code:

```
/* ... */

public function getDataSet() {
  return new \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_YamlDataSet('path/to/yaml/data');
}

/* ... */

public function testFoo() {
  // setup state and run operations

  // load expected data to test against
  $expected = new \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_YamlDataSet('path/to/expected/yaml');
  static::assertTablesEqual($expected->getTable('foo'), $this-getConnection()->createDataSet('foo'));
}
```

I would like to just be able to do

```
// fooSeedData.yml
foo:
  - id: 1
  # ...


// fooExpectedData.yml
foo_test1:
# ...

foo_test2:
# ...

// fooTest.php
public function foo_test1() {
  /* ... */
  $expected->getTable('foo_test1')
  /* ... */
}

public function foo_test2() {
  /* ... */
  $expected->getTable('foo_test2')
  /* ... */
}
```

but `static::assertTablesEqual($expected, $actual);` compares table names along with the data. Requiring a dataset file per test. Having numerous dataset files seems excessive which makes me think I'm doing something wrong.

Is there a way to do this? Am I using phpunit/dbunit wrong? If so how should I be doing this? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: not sure i understood the problem correclty. But if the concern is about convenient handling of multiple expectation datasets you might want to consider using [`array datasets`](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit/blob/m‌​aster/src/DataSet/Ar‌​rayDataSet.php) for the expected data along with [querying tables](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/database.html#database.asserting-the-result-of-a-query) for actual data. Array data sets are simple to create and easy to maintain so they usually fit perfectly to making per-testmethod datasets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using array datasets per @xmike's recommendation.

```
$expected = new \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_ArrayDataSet([
  'table' => [
    ['column' => 'value'] // row
  ]
])

static::assertTablesEqual(/* ... */) // run tests against array dataset
```

This has a couple of nice advantages. Firstly I don't have to use external data files and can keep data in next to the tests. And secondly this is just way simpler and easier to understand.